# xamarin for android :How to setTextColor Set Xml Selector

Tags: android, xamarin, textview, xamarin.android

I want XML color selector to set a `TextView` in Java code.

```
mText.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.xml_color_selector))
```

How does this code work in Xamarin?

I found the API from [here 1](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3AAndroid.Content.Res.ColorStateList) and [here 2](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M:Java.Lang.Class.GetResource). I tried both of them, but:

```
mText.SetTextColor(Android.Content.Res.Resources. "not found GetColorStateList"<br>
mText.SetTextColor(Resources. "not found GetColorStateList"
mText.SetTextColor(Java.Lang.ClassLoader. "Not Found GetResource"
mText.SetTextColor(Java.Lang.Class. "Not Found GetResource"
```

Thanks.

P.S. I want to convert Java code to C# code
and set the XML selector to `Textcolor` in code.

This is Resources\Drawable\xml_color_selector.xml
I hope Set this `TextColor` drawable in `Activity`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="@color/menu_item_title_color_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
  <item android:color="@color/menu_item_title_color" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

This action `SetBackground` works fine.

```
ListItemView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.menu_item_background_color_pressed);
```

Comment: found.  ListItemText.SetTextColor(Context.Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.menu_item_title_color_selector_activated));

Answer (score 2):

This was a headache for me too. Since the more intuitive `GetColor(int)` was deprecated by Google, you **can't** do this anymore.

```
view.SetTextColor(context.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.color_name));
```

Instead you should use `GetColor(int, Theme)` in any of these ways

```
view.SetTextColor(context.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.color_name, null)); 
view.SetTextColor(context.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.color_name, theme));
```

However, this is only available from API 23 going forward, therefore if you want to support older devices, many Java developers will propose to use

```
view.SetTextColor(ContextCompat.GetColor(context, Resource.Color.color_name));
```

Now for us, Xamarin developers, this **won't** work either since it'll show an error saying that it can't convert `int` to `ColorStateList`. So, instead you should use

**SOLUTION:**

```
view.SetTextColor(ContextCompat.GetColorStateList(context, Resource.Color.color_name));
```

Hope the explanation helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can set it in xml
if you want to select it as background color then write

```
  android:background="@color/xml_color_selector"
```

and your `xml_color_selector.xml` file should be in color folder in res.

if you want to add border only then you should keep xml_color_selector.xmlin drawable folder and then write

```
android:background="@drawable/xml_color_selector"
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I hope to change Text Color Resource in my code, Not axml setting

Answer (score 0):

```
mText.SetBackgroundColor (Color.Transparent);
```

Make sure that Color is an xml file in your resource directory (Resources -> Values -> Color.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="solid_red">#fff000</color>
    <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="lightgrey">#bbbbbb</color>
    <color name="grey">#333333</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="listseparator">#2A3748</color>
    <color name="yellow">#FECF35</color>
    <color name="blue">#00f</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: That is xamarin code. Came out of an Android app that I developed using Xamarin and is in the app. Xamarin uses resource files.